# Roland D5 Acoustic Piano

Tags: synthesizer

I just got synthesizer roland D5 from family member and trying to playing some piano patch but sounds really bad. Can roland D5 have grand piano sounds or acoustic piano sound? Please let me know how to do that. I have check the manual instruction book to doing some sound engineering but its still bad. Can we transfer file from computer to this midi?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The D5 doesn't have any presets for Grand Piano. The piano patches are a01 to a03, with the best one being a01 (with 3 partials) as the other two only have 2 partials.

You can use the D5 as a midi keyboard to play much better quality patches on your PC or some other device, but you cannot send higher quality sounds to play on the D5 - it is fairly limited.

It's worthwhile reading the manual - it describes everything you can do in very simple terms.

Comment: In the manual book edit volume p. 98 mentioned about creating acoustic piano but I cannot get the best quality of acoustic piano, its weird in my ears.

Comment: So if I connected this synthesizer to PC and install some app like cubase than I can get many piano patches and great sound piano quality?

Comment: If you like, yes